Where is "Show command line afterwards" in PyCharm 23.2.3
I can't find the setting of "Show command line afterwards" in PyCharm 23.2.3

I tried to locate the setting for 'Show command line afterwards' in PyCharm 23.2.3, but I couldn't find it. I was expecting to easily find this setting in the 'run configurations' menu, but it seems to be missing. Can you help me find it?

I don't have PyCharm but maybe 23.2.3 doesn't have this function. OR maybe this function is only in payed version
